# How to indicate that I want perform a join of five tables specifying that there are two tables after the FROM clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to perform a join between five tables (person, family, gender, Relationship, and household). I'm able to join person, family, gender, and relationship with the first query below, but have difficulty when trying to join the fifth table, household, which the family table has a foreign key for. I suppose my main problem is identifying the correct syntax to use in this case because the person table references all other tables, as seen in the first query below, except for the household table, the household table being referenced by the family table.
I have included the query I tried when trying to join the household table (Query #2). Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Query #1:

```
SELECT person.Id, person.firstName, person.lastName, person.birthdate, gender.gender, family.id, Relationship.description
FROM (((person
INNER JOIN gender on person.gender = gender.Id)
INNER JOIN family on person.idFamily = family.Id)
INNER JOIN Relationship on person.capRelationship = Relationship.id);
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT person.Id, person.firstName, person.lastName, person.birthdate, gender.gender, family.id, Relationship.description
FROM person, family
INNER JOIN gender on person.gender = gender.Id)
INNER JOIN family on person.idFamily = family.Id)
INNER JOIN Relationship on person.capRelationship = Relationship.id)
INNER JOIN household on family.idHousehold = household.id;
```

Comment: Why are you using parentheses in the `FROM` clause?  They are not needed.  And what is so hard about adding `INNER JOIN household on family.idHousehold = household.id` to the first query?

Comment: What actual problem did you have? error? incorrect data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be an issue with the parenthesis and the first table shows person, family. See the updated query below.

```
SELECT person.Id, person.firstName, person.lastName, person.birthdate, gender.gender, family.id, Relationship.description
FROM person
INNER JOIN gender on person.gender = gender.Id
INNER JOIN family on person.idFamily = family.Id
INNER JOIN Relationship on person.capRelationship = Relationship.id
INNER JOIN household on family.idHousehold = household.id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that put me on the right track. This is the query I ran: SELECT person.Id AS PersonID, person.firstName + ' ' + person.lastName AS Name, person.birthdate, gender.gender, family.Id AS FamilyID, Relationship.description AS Relationship, household.Id AS HouseholdID
FROM person
INNER JOIN gender on person.gender = gender.Id
INNER JOIN family on person.idFamily = family.Id
INNER JOIN Relationship on person.capRelationship = Relationship.Id
INNER JOIN household on family.idHousehold = household.Id;

Comment: That is great new. Feel free to rate me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **")"** from first three inner join in your query #2. I do believe this will solve your problem.

Btw, you dont have to use **";"** if you are using sql server management studio.